# Does ImageMagick have a native format?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am creating images with the PHP *Imagick* extension in several steps.

I would like to cache intermediate results to disk.

Is there a format that I can use that preserves all channels and preferably also settings?

```
$i = new Imagick();
$i->setImagecolorspace();
$i->compositeImage(...);
$i->setImageBackgroundColor(...);

$i->setImageFormat(???);
$i->writeImage('cache.im');

$i2 = new Imagick();
$i2->readImage('cache.im');
```

Now `$i2` should be the exact same image as `$i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul says, it is MPC which is basically a memory dump of the file in two parts - one, the header including all metadata and two, the pixels - unencoded and uncompressed so that it can be read directly into memory without any CPU effort.

So, for example:

```
convert -size 4x4 xc:white a.mpc
```

yields

```
-rw-------  1 mark  staff  128 23 Sep 09:29 a.cache     <--- the pixel array
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  357 23 Sep 09:35 a.mpc       <--- the header and metadata
```

where `a.mpc` contains

```
id=MagickCache
magick-signature=4026865107
class=DirectClass  colors=0  matte=False
columns=4  rows=4 depth=16
colorspace=sRGB
page=4x4+0+0
rendering-intent=Perceptual
gamma=0.454545
red-primary=0.64,0.33  green-primary=0.3,0.6  blue-primary=0.15,0.06
white-point=0.3127,0.329
date:create=2015-09-23T09:35:05+01:00
date:modify=2015-09-23T09:35:05+01:00
```

and `a.cache` contains

```
xxd -g4 a.cache
0000000: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000010: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000020: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000030: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000040: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000050: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000060: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
0000070: ffffffff ffff0000 ffffffff ffff0000  ................
```

Another format that preserves all metadata is the `MIFF` format. You would use that like this:

```
convert -size 4x4 xc:white MIFF:a
```

which yields this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     439 23 Sep 09:37 a
```

and looks like this:

```
more a
id=ImageMagick  version=1.0
class=DirectClass  colors=0  matte=False
columns=4  rows=4  depth=16
colorspace=sRGB
page=4x4+0+0
rendering-intent=Perceptual
gamma=0.454545
red-primary=0.64,0.33  green-primary=0.3,0.6  blue-primary=0.15,0.06
white-point=0.3127,0.329
date:create=2015-09-23T09:37:04+01:00
date:modify=2015-09-23T09:37:04+01:00
^L
:^Z<FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF>
<FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF>
<FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF>
<FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF><FF>
```

A nice feature of the MIFF format is that it is *"streaming"* which means you can append/concatenate arbitrary numbers of images together in a single file.

One factor to be aware of... it is not advisable to use these formats for long-term storage as they are not guaranteed to be compatible across `ImageMagick` releases or platforms.